# Returning to Calling Page Within an Area Using UrlReferrer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, areas

I have created a new MVC2 project using the ASP.NET MVC2 Web Application, which gives me the default web site. I have added a simple area in which I had a Home Controller and an Index view. That cuased the first problem with the compiler giving "Multiple types were found that match the Controller name 'Home'". I changed Home to Main and it compiled.

I added a new tab to reference the Index view in my area, opened the website and started clicking the tabs. When I visited the Area index page, I couldn't go back to the Home or About page without changing the menu, as follows:

```
<ul id="menu">              
     <li><%= Html.ActionLink("SampleArea.Main", "Index", "Main", new { area = "SampleArea" }, null)%></li>
     <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)%></li>
     <li><%= Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)%></li>
</ul>
```

I could then cycle through the tabs correctly. I then changed the code in the LogOff view in the Account controller, as follows:

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    FormsService.SignOut();

    //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    return RedirectToAction(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath.ToString());
}
```

I am using UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath to return to the calling page if the User logs off. If the calling page happens to be the View in SampleArea, .AbsolutePath contains "/SampleArea". This is because the controller and view are the defaults, and so they are not included. As it continues, I get the following error message:

> The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Account/SampleArea

My understanding is that /Account has been added because that is the controller it was in when LogOff was executed. It thinks /SampleArea is an action and therefore added the current controller to complete the route.

Using UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath, is there any way I can specify SampleArea as an area, or is there something else I can do to return to the correct page?

**New Addition**
This is even stranger than I thought. I opened the website I am currently developing and changed the return statement in view LogOut to return using AbsolutePath. A breakpoint reveals it contains "/Club/PrivacyPolicy". However, I get the same error message with the following difference:

> Requested URL: /Login/Club/PrivacyPolicy

Why on earth should it prefix it with /Login which is a View, rather than /Account which is a Controller? In fact, why should it prefix it with anything at all? /Club/PrivacyPolicy
 is a valid route in Global.asax.cs.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but I would be careful relying on UrlReferrer as some proxy servers and firewalls strip it out of the response as a security measure.

Comment: Why is that? Surely the value has been set by the system so there should be no suggestion of malicious injection, should there?

Comment: referrer is often cut out by firewalls, antiviruses, proxies, etc. So you should not rely your code logic on this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out how to return to the page you were on when you triggered the LogOn or LogOut request. I have used the following piece of code.

```
Html.ActionLink("Member LogOn", "LogOn", "Account", new { area = "", returnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl }, null)
```

This generates

```
<a href='/LogIn/LogOn?returnUrl=%2FContactUs'>Member LogOn</a>
```

for example.

In my HttpPost ActionResult LogOn, I then have

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
{
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
    else
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Sometimes I find I just need HttpContext.Request.RawUrl.

I'm not quite sure why it has generated /LogIn/LogOn instead of /Account/LogOn, but it works as expected.

Comment: I have found the reason it had /LogIn/LogOn instead of /Account/LogOn. I changed from LogIn to LogOn for the View name but I didn't change the routing definitions in Global.aspx. Once I changed them it became /Account/LogOn.

Comment: The above piece of code could lead to a Open Redirection attack. In MVC3, the "if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))" should be coded as "if (Url.IsLocalUrl( returnUrl ))". THis is courtesy of Jon Galloway's latest blog.